# Does $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ have idempotent under convolution operation.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

One can easily prove that there does not exist any $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f*f=f$ holds due to Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. But what about the case when $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})?$ Is there any counterexample or is there any such function which fails to exist?

Comment: Take Fourier transform.

Comment: @geetha290krm See this solution please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f\in L^2(\Bbb R^d)$ is a solution to $f*f = f$. Then $g:=\mathcal F(f)\in L^2$ by Plancherel and in the sense of distributions (see the Lemma below),
$$
g^2 = g
$$
Since $g\in L^2$, one deduces that the above identity holds a.e. and so $g$ is an indicator function. Since $g\in L^2$, it is the **indicator function of a set of finite measure**.

Conversely, if $g$ is the indicator function of a set of finite measure, then $g\in L^1$ and $g^2\in L^1$ and $g^2=g$, so taking the Fourier transform in the classical sense, $f*f=f$.

---

**Lemma:** if $f\in L^2$, then in the sense of distributions, $\mathcal F(f*f) = \mathcal F(f)^2$.

*Proof:* let $f_n$ be a sequence of $C^\infty_c$ functions converging to $f$ in $L^2$. Then $\mathcal F(f_n)^2\to \mathcal F(f)^2$ in $L^1$ (because $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ and by Cauchy-Schwarz), and so in the sense of (tempered) distributions.

Moreover, $f_n*f_n$ converges to $f*f$ in $L^\infty$ by Young's inequality (write $f_n*f_n-f*f = f_n*(f_n-f) + (f_n-f)*f$), therefore, for any Schwartz function $\varphi$, $\langle f_n*f_n,\mathcal F \varphi \rangle \to \langle f*f,\mathcal F \varphi \rangle$, that is $\mathcal F(f_n*f_n)\to \mathcal F(f*f)$ in the sense of distributions.

Finally, for every $n$, $\mathcal F(f_n)^2 = \mathcal F(f_n*f_n)$, so taking the limit in the sense of distributions, $\mathcal F(f)^2 = \mathcal F(f*f)$

Comment: For $f,g\in L^2(\Bbb{R})$, is there a definition of $f*g$ other than to say $\xi=\mathcal F(f)\mathcal F(g)$ is $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R})$ by Cauchy-Schwarz (on intervals), so $\xi$ is a tempered distribution, then let $f*g:=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\xi)$?  I mean, the integral $\xi_2(x):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-t)g(t)dt$ converges pointwise for all $x$ as an inner product in $L^2(\Bbb{R})$, but that doesn't establish anything about its properties.

Comment: Yes, $f*g = \int f(x-y)\,g(y)\,\mathrm d y$ is defined through the usual formula here, and $f*g$ is thus continuous and vanishing at infinity by Young's inequality. This can be seen also in the proof of the lemma where $f*f$ is the uniform limit of test functions.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I've always thought on $L^2(\Bbb{R})$ the convolution is defined *via* the transform.

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with a solution. Intuitively if I take the fourier transformation on both side of the equation
\begin{align}
f*f=f,
\end{align}
then it suggest that $\hat{f}$ is sort of indicator function of a set $A$ of finite measure.
Now, I come to the rigorous solution, let's take $g=\chi_A$, where $\lambda(A)<\infty$. Now take the inverse Fourier transform $F^{-1}(g)$ and let's call it $f$. Clearly $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$ Now to prove
\begin{align}
f*f=f.
\end{align}
Clearly, $f*f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)f(x-t) dt$ exist pointwise due to Cauchy--Schwartz inequality.
Now, Let's take , $h=F^{-1}(g^2)$, we will prove that $h=f*f$ a.e.
\begin{align}
h(x)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g^2(t) e^{ixt} dt a.e.\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(f) F(f) e^{ixt} dt\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(f)(t) F(\tau_{-x} f)(t) dt\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(-t) f(t+x) dt\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) f(x-t) dt\\
&=f*f(x), a.e.
\end{align}
So, $f*f=h=F^{-1}(g^2)=F^{-1}(g)=f$, since $g^2=g.$

Comment: If $f\in L^2$, then $f*f$ is continuous and converges to $0$ at infinity by Young's inequality, and so is a tempered distribution. The identity $F(f*f) = F(f)^2$ is then valid in the sense of distributions.

Comment: @LL3.14 but how does that help?

Comment: It was just to answer your sentence "many people just take ...".

Comment: @LL3.14 can you write your solution precisely and rigorously then it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @LL3.14 can you write your solution precisely and rigorously then it will be very helpful for me. Also I am sorry for the comment such as "Many people....."